# Open app e.g. Word then open file via FireFox (for WebDav integration)

Tags: c#, javascript, firefox, ms-word, webdav

I'm writing a custom WebDav integration for our website and in IE I can use `new ActiveXObject` to open e.g. Word from javascript then open a file. It's got to be like this to enable the applications WebDav integration, I can't just use a link.

We support Firefox as a browser however and `new ActiveXObject` doesn't work. I've toyed with writing a Silverlight 4 app which apparently can open Word on the user's desktop or even asking the user to download some sort of Console app that launches Word/Excel/etc. I don't want to do this though and I keep thinking someone must have had this issue before.

So.. is there a way to open Word from Firefox FIRST, THEN open a url from Word.

Cheers,

Adam.

UPDATE: Silverlight 4 no longer an option, don't want to use OOB

Comment: There problem here doesn't seem to be WebDAV but authentication. Word is able to open files from WebDAV directly, e.g. when you call `winword.exe http://example.com/mydocument.docx` on the command line. How do users identify themselves to the WebDAV server?

Comment: Hi, well currently a temporary secure url is created on the fly that authenticates the user server side bc for some reason any sort of challenge to Word makes it open read-only. So yep that's exactly what I want to call - winword.exe <generated url>

Comment: Decided to just show url and "Copy to Clipboard" button in Firefox using ZeroClipboard, telling the user to open url in particular app, in case anybody in interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in plain HTML. But a firefox extension should allow this.